# Measurable selection for conditional expectation

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, convex-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, and $\mathcal{X}\subset \mathcal{F}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. Let $X$ be an $\mathcal{X}$-measurable random variable and   $Y$ be an $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variable. Then given a bounded continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, is it possible to ensure  that  there exists an $\mathcal{X}$-measurable random variable $Z$ such that
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)\mid \mathcal{X}] =f(X,Z).
$$
Does the condition that $\{f(x,y)\mid y\in  \textrm{Range}(Y)\}$ is convex for all $x$ help?

---

It is clear that if $ f(x,y)=g(x)y$ for all $x,y$, then   $Z=\mathbb{E}[Y\mid \mathcal{X}]$ satisfies the requirement. I was wondering whether it is possible to go beyond this affine case.